# Find all Linear Transformations with specified Image and Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

$T: R^3 -> R^3$

Find all the linear transformations such that:

1. The vectors

$$v = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$w = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

are a basis for the kernel of $T$ and

2. The image of $T$ is a line that has a direction vector

$$s = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Equal vectors have a hard time forming a basis together.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Extend $\{w, v\}$ to a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.  You know every linear map is uniquely identified by where it sends a basis and you already know $w$ and $v$ should go to zero.  Your third basis element must then get sent to something on the line with direction vector $s$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You are given the equations
$$Tx = (0,0,s)^T \qquad \forall x$$
Wich already necessitates $T_{ij} = 0 \forall i=1,2; j=1..3$.
$$T = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\&t^T&}$$
And for $t$ you are given the equations
$$t^T v = t^T w = 0$$
This will give you a one-dimensional solution space with basis $(1,1,-1)^T$, so
$$T = \lambda \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&1&-1}$$